# File path not getting in ajax "URL" in wordpress. Showing error of 404.?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have given file name like "counter.php" in "URL" of ajax code that file is located in wordpress root directory but its giving error of file not found. Kindly check the code detail. How should i add the ajax   code in wordpress and file in root directory .

> Network Error: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/wordpress/list/counter.php

this is my AJAX code

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST", //by post method
    url: "counter.php", // file name
    data: { id: ID },
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's simply that the URL is incorrect. Either the relative path is wrong, or routing hasn't been set up properly.

Comment: ...which means that _counter.php_ does not exist - at least not in the default path.

Comment: run your file url in browser and then check what is wrong in url

Comment: yes i know but what should i do?

Comment: why are you not using wordpress ajax methods

Comment: Hiii yatendra , Which ajax methods you are talking about actually i am new in wordpress. I don't have much knowledge about this.

Comment: follow this tutorial for using wordpress ajax http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/

Answer (score 1):

you haven't given the path correctly of the file counter.php and you must have to include the database connection in that file..